# Existence of an analytic function in a unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$.Then, is it true that there exists a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{D} \to\mathbb{D}$ such that $f(\frac{1}{2})=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $f'(\frac{1}{4})=1$? 
Can we use Schwarz's lemma to solve it?

Comment: If $f(1/4)=1$ then $f$ is not $\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$...

Comment: There is an issue here. If you want $f(1/4)=1$, then the target of $f$ cannot be $\mathbb{D}$. Fixing some of the assumptions from here I think the maximum modulus principle will be helpdul here.

Comment: Your function is not $\Bbb D \to \Bbb D$

Comment: Sorry ,I made a mistake, it Wii be derivative of f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a double application of [Schwarz-Pick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma); let $f(1/4)=w$

first $1=|f'(1/4)| \le \frac{1-|w|^2}{1-|1/4|^2}$, so one gets $|w| \le 1/4$

then: $|\frac{f(1/2)-f(1/4)}{1-\overline {f(1/2)} f(1/4)}| \le |\frac{(1/2)-(1/4)}{1-\overline {(1/2)} (1/4)}| =\frac {2}{7}$, so:

$|\frac{2w+1}{2+w}| \le \frac {2}{7}$ with $|w| \le 1/4$

But (see below for a direct proof) $|\frac{2w+1}{2+w}| \ge |\frac{2(-1/4)+1}{2+(-1/4)}|=2/7$ when $|w| \le 1/4$ with equality iff $w=-1/4$ hence we get $f(1/4)=-1/4$ and $f$ is a disc automorphism as we have equality in Schwarz-PIck, while it is obvious that $f(z)=-z$ is the only such, but $f'(1/4)=-1$ so contradiction and no such function exists!

(for example $|\frac{2w+1}{2+w}| =|2-\frac{3}{2+w}| \ge 2-|\frac{3}{2+w}|$, while $-|\frac{3}{2+w}| \ge -|\frac{3}{2+(-1/4)}|=-12/7$ since $|2+w| \ge |2+(-1/4)|, |w| \le 1/4$)

Comment: @Conard thanks for your answer ! But I think it could have been made shorter as $|\frac{2w+1}{w+2}|\leq \frac{2}{7} $ gives $w \leq -\frac{1}{4}$ and from first inequality we have the reverse

Comment: $w$ is complex though, so one had to be careful